# Unexplainable segmentation fault

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

I'm getting a segmentation fault here for some reason. I have no idea why. Any help?

```
typedef struct gw_struct{
    int pop;
    int col;
    int row;
    struct district ***gw;
    struct person **people;
};

typedef struct gw_struct *GW;
```

and then later in a function...

```
GW world;
struct district ***array = malloc(nrows*sizeof(struct district**));
    int i, j;
for (i = 0; i < nrows; i++)
{
    array[i] = malloc(ncols*sizeof(struct district*));
    for (j = 0; j<ncols; j++)
    {
            array[i][j] = malloc(sizeof(struct district));
    }
}   

world->gw = array; //this is the line that gives the seg fault
```

Comment: did you intialise pointer world????

Answer (score 2):

Your code doesn't initialize `world`, so presumably it points off into the weeds someplace when you try to dereference it in that line.  Make sure to intialize variables before you use them.

Comment: I doubt it - are you sure you're showing us the right (accurate) code?

Comment: You're right. It should have been struct gw_struct, I didn't fix it, and I didn't notice during compiling because I've been ignoring some warnings. Thank you.

Comment: @SwiftCore You've asked quite a few questions, with answers, so saying this just in case: once the problem is solved (or just not relevant any more), you should *accept* (click the tick mark at upper left corner of) the one answer you think is best (unless they're all wrong and unacceptable, in which case you could leave a comment, or answer your own question with correct answer). This serves as signal, that no more answers are needed.

Answer (score -1):

Your issue is on the first line `GW world;`, this is not properly referenced in memory.

This should work:

```
GW *world;
struct district ***array = malloc(nrows*sizeof(struct district**));
    int i, j;
for (i = 0; i < nrows; i++)
{
    array[i] = malloc(ncols*sizeof(struct district*));
    for (j = 0; j<ncols; j++)
    {
            array[i][j] = malloc(sizeof(struct district));
    }
}   

world->gw = array; //this is the line that gives the seg fault
```

Your World variable declaration needs to be a pointer, this will properly reference your initialized struct in memory and will allow you to make your assignment.

Comment: Please add some details that, why you have posted this code, and how it will help to solve the problem.